# Testing: Stubbing reauthenticateWithCredential Difficulty with Mocks

Tags: dart, firebase-authentication, mocking, mockito, stub

I've been having difficulty getting this stub to work. My solution that I'd expect to work is

```
when(user.reauthenticateWithCredential(MockAuthCredential())).thenAnswer((_) async => MockUserCredential());
```

But I keep getting the error

> The following MissingStubError was thrown running a test:
> 'reauthenticateWithCredential'
> No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
> reauthenticateWithCredential(AuthCredential(providerId: password, signInMethod: password, token:
> null))
> Add a stub for this method using Mockito's 'when' API, or generate the mock for MockUser with
> 'returnNullOnMissingStub: true'.

The implementation of reauthenticateWithCredential if needed for reference

```
  Future<UserCredential> reauthenticateWithCredential(
    AuthCredential credential,
  ) async {
    return UserCredential._(
      _auth,
      await _delegate.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential),
    );
  }
```

Also how my locator is set up

```
late User user;
user = MockUser();
locator.registerSingleton<User>(user);
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to change

late User user into late MockUser user and then in place of MockAuthCredential() use any.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.